# How do I get django template to recognize manytomanyfield comparison?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, many-to-many

In my project, I am currently trying to access a manytomany field and compare it to another.  I have several cases where I am doing something similar and it is working .  The difference in this case is that I am trying to essentially say if one of the values in this many to many field equals a value in this other manytomanyfield, then do something....

Here is my code...

```
Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ManyToManyField(Name)

Userprofile(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ManyToManyField(Name)
```

In my Django template I am trying to do something like...

```
{% If user_publisher in form.initial.publisher_set.all %} 
{{ publisher.name }}
{% endif %}
```

The example above is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do....I'm essentially trying to compare the manytomany fields and if any of the values match, perform an action.  I've been at this most of today and have tried several combinations.

If I do something like

```
{% if user in form.initial.publisher.all %}
```

This works fine.  I'm struggling to try and figure out how I can compare manytomanyfields.  I suspect the user query works fine because it's not a manytomanyfield.

I'm thinking my format is off.  I have tried to use the _set to publisher and the user publisher and when I go so far as to print the output, I am actually seeing that both the user_publisher and publisher querysets are the same.  However, my django template is not showing me any results.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

I have surfed SO all afternoon as well as Google, but can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is more detail to my issue.  I am currently doing a CreateView whereby I am trying to get an existing record by overriding get_initial as shown below:

```
class BookUpdateView(CreateView):
    model = Book 
    form_class = Book
    template_name = 'Book/update_book.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(BookUpdateView, self).get_initial()
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
        initial = book.__dict__.copy()

        initial.update({
             "publisher": publisher.all(),
        })
        return initial
```

Because I am copying in these records as a starting point and this is a CreateView, I don't yet have a PK or ID to query from a get_context_data perspective.  Not sure how to go about getting the data that I am copying in but have not yet saved.  I am actually trying to figure out if a user has the same publisher via their user profile and was able to figure out the format for get_context_data as shown below:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(BookUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user_publisher = self.request.user.userprofile.publisher.all()
    return context
```

I tried to do something like....

```
{% if user_publisher in form.initial.publisher_set.all %}
```

But the template never recognizes that these two in fact do match...

When I print the variables....

They both show...

```
<QuerySet [<Publisher: ACME Publishing>]>
<QuerySet [<Publisher: ACME Publishing>]>
```

But the template does not recognize that they are the same.  The screen is not rendered as I would expect when using the template language above.  No errors, but end result isn't what I would expect either.  Thanks in advance for any additional thoughts.

Comment: Why don't you do the comparison in the view function?

Comment: @truecam  Thanks for the suggestion.  The reason I was trying to use the template language is because I am copying in data from another record into this CreateView, and can't seem to get at the data using get_initial either.  I can copy in the data but when I try to compare one many to many field vs. the other it is not working.

Comment: Are you getting any template errors?

Comment: Why not try iterating through author set and checking if each one is in the publisher set?

Comment: @truecam I have updated my original question with more details.  I am not getting any errors and I'm struggling with iterating through the publisher data as outlined above.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day or two of thinking about this, was able to figure out how to grab the PK and then use it in the context so that I could leverage the information via the context and not the form directly.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateProcedureView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk=self.kwargs["pk"]
        publisher = Publisher.objects.filter(pk=pk).filter(individual_access=self.request.user).count()
        return context
```

Then in the form I can say something like if publisher > 0 then do something fancy.  Thanks for the suggestions along the way to help me think this through.